# Can you guarantee that there exist at least 2 students with the same answers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

Suppose you are evaluating $1600$ students with a test of $15$ numerated questions. When u correct the test, you see that none of them answered correctly to $2$ consecutive questions. If C is correct and I is incorrect, can you guarantee that there exist at least 2 students with the same sequence of C and I (ICICICICICICICI for example) on all of the $15$ answers?
I guess I can do a tree, see all possibilites and apply Dirichlet's principle. But I think problem has a to have a better approach, one that is valid for even large numbers.

Comment: Did every student get exactly 2 correct answers, and they happened to be adjacent, or could they get more correct answers as long as at least 2 were adjacent?

Comment: Arthur, I edited the post, I meant that none of the students answered correctly to any 2 consecutive answers

Comment: This is still a bit unclear.  How many possible answers are there to each question?  Is it true/false?

Comment: @MW I have edited the question to it is more clear, what you are looking for is the correct and incorrect output in each of the question, so you do not really mind how many possible answers are there on each question. In fact, you can suppose there are only 2.

Comment: Hint: Fibonacci

Comment: @RobPratt Really nice hint!!